# How do I retrieve items from a List<T> where one property contains exactly the words from another list?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to retrieve only the items from a `List<T>` where one of the properties contains the words from another list.

Once it works I will use the code on my actual database, but the below is basically what I want to do.

```
List<string> WordsList = new List<string>();

WordsList.Add("THIS");
WordsList.Add("CAT");

List<Sentence> SentencesList = new List<Sentence>();

SentencesList.Add(new Sentence { Description = "THIS SENTENCE CONTAINS THE WORD DOG" });
SentencesList.Add(new Sentence { Description = "THIS SENTENCE CONTAINS THE WORD CAT" });
SentencesList.Add(new Sentence { Description = "THIS SENTENCE CONTAINS THE WORD DOG AND THE WORD CAT" });
SentencesList.Add(new Sentence { Description = "THIS SENTENCE CONTAINS NEITHER" });
```

Now I want to get the items from SentencesList that contain only the words `"THIS"` **and** `"CAT`"

```
var records = SentencesList.Where(x => WordsList.Any(y => x.Description.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

The above piece of code retrieves all items because they contain `"THIS"` **or** `"CAT"`

Comment: change `WordsList.Any` to  `WordsList.All`

Comment: Wow! Thanks worked like a charm. Please add it as an answer so I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change **or** into **and** logic, all you have to do is to change `WordsList.Any` into `WordsList.All` condition:

```
 var records = SentencesList
   .Where(x => WordsList.All(y => x.Description.Contains(y)))
   .ToList();
```

Now we want *all words* in `WordsList` to be in `x`